# Configure MIFARE DESFire EV1 as NFC Forum Type 4 Tag for NDEF

Tags: android, tags, nfc, mifare, ndef

I started my studies using NFC in Android. I can easily read and write in NDEF format.

My problem is with **MIFARE DESFire EV1**, I have some factory cards and I understand that they do not conform to the **NFC Forum type 4 Tag** specification and, consequently, do not accept to be read or written in NDEF format (when in their factory configuration).

I can get access to the tag through `android.nfc.tech.NfcA` or `android.nfc.tech.IsoDep`.

So far I understand that I need to use `IsoDep.transceive()` method to pass commands that enable me to build an NFC Forum Type 4 compliant tag.

But I'm having a lot of trouble. I'm using TagWriter and it does the service perfectly. Every time I use the NDEF dataset it automatically performs a routine that makes the card an NFC Forum Type 4 Tag and, consequently, an NDEF tag.

However, I could not find any simple example to do this procedure myself. Even after reading the specification document NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0, I'm still very lost.

Is there any practical example to do the process that the TagWriter application does?

- Recognize `NfcA` / `IsoDep` (ok here)
- Make the card conform to the NFC Forum Type 4 Tag specification
- Start recognizing the tag as `android.nfc.tech.Ndef`
- Enable read and write of NDEF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedure to prepare MIFARE DESFire EV1 as an NFC Forum Type 4 Tag (V2.0) is not part of the platform independend NFC Forum specifications. Instead, this procedure is defined by the chip manufacturer (NXP) in their application note [AN11004: MIFARE DESFire as Type 4 Tag](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11004.pdf). The procedure is about the following:

1. If Android already detects the `Ndef` tag technology, you are done. Since Android tries to detect the NDEF tag application and an NDEF message contained in the NDEF data file, finding the `Ndef` tag technology means that the tag is already prepared for NDEF (i.e. it already is configured as NFC Forum Type 4 Tag).
2. Else, you would check if the tag really is a DESFire EV1 tag. You can do this based on the type identification procedure described in [AN10833: MIFARE Type Identification Procedure](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10833.pdf) and based on the version information obtained from the DESFire tag.
3. Once you know that the tag is a DESFire EV1 tag (and that you have sufficient access to the master application in order to apply the necessary modifications to the tag, which may require and authentication step), you would first create the NDEF Tag Application. This is a DESFire application that has its ISO 7816-4 DF name (= AID) set to `D2760000850101` during creation. The values that you chose for the DESFire AID, the ISO file ID are not important for proper T4T operation (note that this is different for the pre-EV1 generation of DESFire). The key settings depend on your usage scenario. The only other important parameter that you need to set during application creation is to allow ISO 7816-4 file identifiers for files within the application (bit 5 in the Key Settings 2 byte set to '1').
4. Select the newly created application.
5. Create a new standard data file, the capability container file, with a size of 15 bytes. You need to set the ISO 7816-4 file ID to `E103`. Make sure to allow plain communication by setting the Com.Set. byte to 0x00. Set the Access Rights field so that you can later modify the file contents during the initialization.
6. Create another new standard data file, the NDEF data file. If you only use the tag as NDEF tag, you would typically use all the remaining available space. Set the ISO 7816-4 file ID to `E104`. Make sure to allow plain communication by setting the Com.Set. byte to 0x00. Set the Access Rights field to 0xE000 for a read-only tag or 0xEEE0 for a tag that should allow read and write access through the `Ndef` tag technology.
7. Select the capability container file and write the capability container data to it:

   ```
   000F  20  003A  0034  04 06 E104 xxxx 00 yy
   ```

   where `xxxx` is the size of the NDEF data file and `yy` is 0x00 if the file is freely writable or 0xFF if the file is read-only.
8. Select the NDEF message file and write the first 2 bytes as 0x0000 (in order to indicate that the file is empty).

Note that creating the NDEF Tag Application structures on a DESFire (EV1) card requires you to use either the native or the wrapped native command set of MIFARE DESFire. Since some versions of Android cause known problems with the native commands, you are better off using wrapped native commands. You can find details on the DESFire command set in the DESFire product datasheets (available only under NDA from NXP).

Comment: Can you comment on the byte-order? According doc AN11004, "According to NDEF specification data is represented in Network Byte-Order" (big-endian) yet the APDU commands use LSB first notation. Shouldn't the data above (item 7) be issued in reverse order when sending the APDU command?. I'm pretty confident I was able to setup the application correctly since the NXP app (Android) does recognize "Type 4 Tag version 1" under heading Desfire Applications but if I go to the NDEF tab, "No NDEF-data storage populated" is displayed. So I don't know if my problem is the CC or the NDEF file. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Can you be a bit more specific about which fields you are interested in? Which APDU commands? Are you referring to MIFARE DESFire commands? These use LSB first notation (but that only affects integer fields and not the binary data). The fields in the CC are in the right order (as they should be written to the CC file in my answer above).